# c# - Linking two lists efficiently

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists:

1. Products
2. A list of Product and Warehouse combination containing
       prices/quantities etc.

Two seperate results of sql queries.

The second list has a 'ProductId'.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
foreach(var product in Products)
     var productWarehouses = Warehouses.Where(x=> x.ProductId == productId).ToList();
     product.Warehouses = productWarehouses;
```

Thing is, this takes very, very long.

Note: I've tried splitting Products into chunks of lists and using Parallel.Foreach() and Tasks to take the time down - but still takes very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Join` rather than doing a linear search through the entirety of one collection for each item in the other collection:

```
var query = from product in Products
    join warehouse in Warehouses
    on product.productId equals warehouse.ProductId
    into warehouses
    select new
    {
        product,
        warehouses,
    };
```

Comment: My reaction as I F10 over that - [link](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/98/2a/eb/982aebe2d39aaf5c291f64f526166066.jpg).
Serious tho - thanks :)

Comment: Quick question if you're still here - Is it possible to do something along the lines of 

`select product
{
      Warehouses = warehouses`

instead of mapping all the product fields:

  `select new ProductCustomClass()
                        {
                            ProductId= product.ProductId,`

... I'd like to end up with a List<ProductCustom> instead of List<dynamic>

Comment: @AlanCiantar Try it and see what happens.  If you want to *mutate the product* then you should be doing that in a `foreach`, not using LINQ.  LINQ is for querying.  If you wanted to just use LINQ, then project the query into a new product instance that has the appropriate values set.

Comment: @AlanCiantar Then project the data into a product.  It's your query, do with it what you want.  You have the information you need, you only need to format it how you want it formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in c#, I would prefer to do it in SQL stored procedure. Get all details from one sql and then iterate though result to create Product list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Dictionary<int, Product>` from your `Products` where `Product.ProductID` is used as key:

```
var pd = Products.ToDictionary(p => p.ProductID, p => p);
```

then you can iterate over Warehouses and lookup appropriate products fast:

```
foreach (var wh in Warehouses)
{
    pd[wh.ProductId].Warehouses.Add(wh); //supposed Product.Warehouses lists have already been created, if not, add checks and create them as needed.
}
```